# Cant receive notifications from GCM

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to add notifications to my android app. So I decided to implement GCM.

I have used the sample code from the official documentation 
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

and the sample application
https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/

Here is my implementation

```
   public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "210822831159";

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    Context context;

    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        if (checkPlayServices())
        {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty())
            {
                registerInBackground();
            }
            else
            {
                //"No valid Google Play Services APK found."
            }
        }
        //...
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask&lt;Void, Void, String&gt;() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                //...
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    private SharedPreferences getGcmPreferences(Context context) {
        return getSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // TODO
    }
   //...
}
```

The Broadcaster:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Intent Service:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.HBM.sample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.HBM.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.HBM.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.HBM.sample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app compiles fine and when I set a breakpoint in registerInBackground after:

```
regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

the client registers fine and I get the registration id that looks something like this:

```
APA91bEdxx0UyqtX6qoVuhYNSeJkuAITIpdkbCkBCCsOyX5-lpbtNAJBvvGqIGKqxGhW24-y-tWbj2EDKJAiyvzVhP7jhMevZBr-o-Y6Eli0uG24oWXjFOWa1Sj9vjNXaO5wbWs7WodC4Oq4QOFaPQscF_v44Z_kyg
```

After that I created a GCM Server application and send a notification to the registrationId
Here is the json response:

```
{"multicast_id":5827029040432755439,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1407451852374547%913f6fe1f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

It looks like the app registers fine and the notifications are pushed successfully. But onReceive never fires and I dont get any notifications `o_O`

I have tried the app on two different phones and different networks. But Im not sure what Im doing wrong. I hope someone can help me. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Having similar issues - any solution found?